# What is the fastest route in 80 days?

Tags: 80-days

I have been trying a number of routes from London around the world and back to London in 80 days (Android).

I travelled very efficiently in Central Asia and East Asia although I have found going to Colombo to be a detour.

I struggle every time I land on the American continent.

What route did you chose to complete the around the world trip?

Answer (score 2):

My fastest is 38 days. But that was being cheaty and going via the North Pole. Head to Cambridge and head north and then once to the pole (after the long journey) back to London via Reykjavik.

Massively surprised it worked!

Comment: How do you discover the Cambridge route? When I start the game I can only go to Paris.

Comment: Anyone with a more normal route?

Comment: The North Pole route was added in December for the Android release.  It is available in iOS as a free update. http://www.inklestudios.com/2014/12/05/to-the-pole.html

Comment: The Cambridge route appears after you've played through a few times.